# Estimate for $f^2$ on a Ball from below

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

Let $f\in C^\infty(B_R(0))$, where $R>0$. For $0<\sigma<1$ require the following properties on $f$:

$$ 0\leq f\leq 1,\ f=1 \text{ on } B_{(1-\sigma)R},\ f=0 \text { on }\partial B_R,\ |\nabla f|\leq C(\sigma R)^{-1},\ \text{ and } |\Delta f|\leq C(\sigma R)^{-2}$$

The constant $C$ depends only on the Dimension and the order of derivatives. The $\Delta$ may be replaced by the full Hessian if necessary.

What I want to show, and what seems to be used in several articles is the following inequality:

$$f(x) |\nabla f(x)| \leq C (f^2(x)) (\sigma R)^{-2}$$
where the constant may denepnd on $R$ (if necessary). Of course, this looks a lot like an application of Taylor's formula or of the mean value theorem, but the estimate that are given are somehow in the wrong direction. Could someone provide any hints on that? The result is clear on the set where $f=1$.

I add where this is comming from and post an updated question, since the previous one was answered by Willie Wong.

We have an upper estimate, where we find the integral
$$... \leq ... + C\int_{B_R} |u(x)-u(x_0)| g^2 f|\nabla f|$$
for some $u,g\in H^1(B_R)$ and such that $|u(x)-u(x_0)|\leq CR^\alpha$.
This term (and several others), is estimated from above by
$$ CR^{2\alpha} \left(\int_{B_R} |\nabla g|^2f^2 +\frac{C}{(\sigma R)^2} \int_{B_R} f^2g^2\right)$$

So as i see it: (and here is the first mistake I made), we use the estimate I suggested (this would only lead to $R^\alpha$ instead of $R^{2\alpha}$. Since this does not work, we use Cauchy's inequality and obtain 
$$C R^{2\alpha} \left(\int_{B_R} f^2g^2 + \int_{B_R} (|\nabla f|)^2g^2\right).$$
The first term can be multiplied by $|B_R|^2/(\sigma R)^2\geq 1$ but for the second term we need now: $$|\nabla f|\leq f (\sigma R)^{-1}$$

But this also seems to fail if we consider the example given by  Willie Wong

Comment: Which articles? There must be further assumptions on $f$. Work in 1D and let $R = 1$ and $\sigma = \frac12$. One can build some $f$ satisfying your hypotheses with $f = \exp ( - 1/(1-x))$ for $x \in (1/4,1)$. Then $$ f|f'| = (1-x)^{-2} f^2$$ is not a bounded multiple of $f^2$.

Comment: e.g. an article of Dibenedetto, Gianazza, Vespri on continuity of the two-phase flow equation, this goes back to an older research report of Alt and DiBendetto.

Comment: particularly, that's why I'm asking the question. I was not able to use this (thus i proceeded differently but their proof works out the same). Could you provide your example as an answer?

Comment: At this point I am more inclined to say that the authors did _not_ use what you think they used. Do you have a more precise reference? (Including page/equation number where this comes up.)

Comment: Probably you are right, I added a deduction for my problem. I also have to admit that I forgot a square and that's why they do not use the estimate I presented. However, I think, in another case they need to use $(|f'|\leq f(\sigma R)^{-1} )$, but even in that case your example applies, doesn't it?

Comment: What do you know about $g$? Also, even with Cauchy's inequality you don't get $R^{2\alpha}$. You are putting the $|u(x) - u(x_0)$ weight on both terms so you cannot square it.

Comment: $g$ is also in $H^1(B_R)$

Comment: Maybe I should emphasize that the appearance of $f$ in the desired estimate puzzles me. Nevertheless, I do not need it since i proceed differently in comparisonto them. However, It would be nice to know if there is an easy way to see this.

Comment: Do you have more properties on $g$, or is it only a function in $H^1$?

Comment: There are no further properties of $g$, it is even worse since it is only in $H^1_{loc}$. However, if one only uses the last but one estimate I gave above, the proofs of these authors work perfectly. Nevertheless, out of interest, I tried to proof these estimates several times during the last months, but always failed :)

Comment: You can even get the estimate if you want: $$...\le C\left(R^{2\alpha}(\sigma R)^{-2}\int f^2g^2+\int g^2\right).$$ By the way, where is this kind of inequality, in the paper that you cited above?

Comment: Hey, thats the estimate I use. The estimate is in Proposition 2.1 (in an older hidden research report by Alt and DiBenedetto a "proof" is given, leaving out the questioned inequality)